# Random Graphs correlation inequalities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

Is there anywhere I can find a proof of the first inequality that $$P(B_{i}| \bigcap_{j \in J} \bar B_{j}) \leq P(B_{i})$$ It is on page $13$ and is the first inequality presented at the start of section $2$ on [these](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Philippe.Chassaing/GDT/documents/SpencerStFlour.pdf) notes ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180103153226/http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Philippe.Chassaing/GDT/documents/SpencerStFlour.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

Using the terminology from the document. The event $A_i \subseteq R$ is increasing (i.e adding points to $R$ does not change the inclusion), and the event $A_j \not\subseteq R$ is decreasing. Also, intersection of decreasing events is still decreasing, and then you can apply Kleitman's lemma or [FKG inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality) which will give you that $B_i$ and $\cap_{j \in J} \bar B_{j}$ are negatively correlated.

Comment: Ok thanks that was useful.

Comment: I was wondering if you could perhaps provide rigorous definitions for increasing and decreasing events in this case? Adding points to $R$ doesn't change the probability that $A_{i} \subseteq R$, but can i not say the same about $A_{j} \not\subseteq R$?